# Finding a custom object in a set and then returning that object

Tags: java

```
public Table findTable(Container container, String name) {
        Iterator<Table> tableFinder = container.getTables().iterator();

        while(tableFinder.hasNext()){
            if (tableFinder.equals(name)){
                return table;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

So basically this method is supposed to search for a table within the object `container`by checking one of its properties `tables`which is a set. It is supposed to find the object through the property `name` which belongs to `Table`. Normally, I would just insert a parameter of type `table`, it'd be easier to find it that way, but the wireframe I was given specifically states that it has to be this way.

I've got hashcode() and equals() as methods for table, I know I need to use them somehow, however I'm not really sure how to do this. The other problem is that I need to return a table and I'm not sure how to do that without an instance of Table so I know that return table is going to give an error. Basically, what I need to know is how to search with `name` and how to get the table out of the set in order to have a valid return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
if (tableFinder.equals(name)){
```

you are calling `equals` of the iterator object, this is not what you really want. Instead you want to compare with the `Table` the iterator is pointing at in each loop. To get that object you need to call the method [Iterator#next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next%28%29) on the iterator object.

```
Table table = tableFinder.next();
if (table.equals(name)){ // assuming that your equals implementation 
                         // compares with the property name of table
```

Comment: This will do, my equals method does compare names.

Answer (score 2):

this required jdk 1.5+:

```
public Table findTable(Container container, String name) {
    for (Table table : container.getTables()) {
        if (table.getName().equals(name)) {// assume you have a getName() method on Table to get table name
            return table;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently comparing the iterator object against the String "name" every time. You should be doing something like this:

```
if (name.equals(tableFinder.next().getName())
```